# How do I avoid a crash into the low-level debugger when compiling ACL2 on SBCL?

Tags: sbcl, acl2

How do I avoid a crash into the low-level debugger when compiling ACL2 on SBCL?  Here is the error message I receive when compiling using SBCL 1.2.3 on Linux:

```
<snip>
ACL2 loading '((COMP-FN :EXEC NIL "1" STATE)).
 NIL

Finished loading '((COMP-FN :EXEC NIL "1" STATE)).

******************************************************************************
          Initialization complete, beginning the check and save.
******************************************************************************
Heap exhausted during garbage collection: 7776 bytes available, 15360 requested.
 Gen StaPg UbSta LaSta LUbSt Boxed Unboxed LB   LUB  !move  Alloc
Waste   Trig    WP  GCs Mem-age
   0:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0        0
  0 10737418    0   0  0.0000
   1:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0        0
  0 10737418    0   0  0.0000
   2:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0        0
  0 10737418    0   0  0.0000
   3: 30389 30230     0     0 12248  2558    25    25     0 448761472
38039936 408790346    0   1  0.8870
   4: 32241 32765 32025 32577  1417  1177   182    42     0 91900528
439696  2000000    0   0  0.0000
   5:     0     0     0     0  1248   157     0     0     0 46039040
  0  2000000 1197   0  0.0000
   6:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0        0
  0  2000000    0   0  0.0000
   Total bytes allocated    = 586701040
   Dynamic-space-size bytes = 1073741824
GC control variables:
   *GC-INHIBIT* = false
   *GC-PENDING* = false
   *STOP-FOR-GC-PENDING* = false
fatal error encountered in SBCL pid 26451(tid 46912509763072):
Heap exhausted, game over.

Welcome to LDB, a low-level debugger for the Lisp runtime environment.
ldb>
```

Answer (score 2):

Matt Kaufmann writes:

> To build ACL2 on SBCL, one must increase memory size beyond the
>   default of 536870912 bytes.  I generally use option
>   "--dynamic-space-size 2000", for example this in my ~/bin/sbcl:

`<some-path>/sbcl-1.2.2-x86-64-linux/src/runtime/sbcl --core <some-path>/sbcl-1.2.2-x86-64-linux/output/sbcl.core --dynamic-space-size 2000 "$@"`